# Missing parameters in Call in TabView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have code that makes my filter bar disappear when user has tapped on a product (a shirt or pair of trousers). This all takes place in the Marketplace tab.

I think the code will work once the bug is fixed however I cannot get rid of the buh about missing arguments.

The code for marketplace is:

```
    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt!
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool
    
    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser!
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                
                
                if !showDetailShirt && !showDetailTrouser {
                
                marketplaceFilterBar
                    
                }
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .shirt {
                    MarketplaceShirtView()
                }
                
                if selectedMarketplaceFilter == .trouser {
                    MarketplaceTrouserView()
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is code for the TabView

```
  @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    
    @StateObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel = SharedDataModel()
    
    @Binding var shirtData : Shirt!
    @Binding var showDetailShirt: Bool

    @Binding var trouserData : Trouser!
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool

    
    // Animation Namespace...
    @Namespace var animation
    
    // Hiding Tab Bar...
    init(){
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            // Tab View...
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                
                
                Marketplace(animation: _animation)
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Market)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Home()
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Home)
                    .setUpTab()
                }
```

On the Marketplace line in the TabView I am getting the error:

Missing arguments for parameters 'shirtData', 'showDetailShirt', 'trouserData', 'showDetailTrouser' in call

UPDATED:
On my MarketplaceShirtView I have the following code:

```
 @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    
    @State private var selectedMarketplaceFilter: MarketplaceFilterViewModel = .shirt
    
    @Namespace var animation : Namespace.ID
    
    @State var showDetailShirt = false

    @State var selectedShirt : Shirt!
    
    // Shared Data...
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
```

When I use an if statement to determine whether to display the Detail view I get the error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Shirt?>’ to expected argument type 'Binding'

Here is the code:

```
 if selectedShirt != nil && showDetailShirt{
                
                ShirtDetailView(shirtData: $selectedShirt, showDetailShirt: $showDetailShirt,animation: _animation)
            }
```

Comment: Those values do not have a default value. You have to provide them.

Comment: @burnsi how would I do this? Especially for a custom object like Shirt / Trouser?

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you posted `MarcetPlace` should be initialized like this:

```
Marketplace(shirtData: $shirtData, showDetailShirt: $showDetailShirt, trouserData: $trouserData, showDetailTrouser: $showDetailTrouser)
```

---

### Edit:

Well you got a custom initializer and properties without default values there so probably you have to initialize those too.

E.g.

```
init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt>, .....
```

### Edit 2:

To be more precise, in your TabView:

```
// Hiding Tab Bar...
init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt?>, showDetailShirt: Binding<Bool>, trouserData: Binding<Trouser?>, showDetailTrouser: Binding<Bool>){
    self._shirtData = shirtData
    self._showDetailShirt = showDetailShirt
    self._trouserData = trouserData
    self._showDetailTrouser = showDetailTrouser
    
    UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
}
```

I don´t think you need those implicit unwrappings so instead of `@Binding var shirtData : Shirt!` use `@Binding var shirtData : Shirt` and in the initializer `init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt?>,` would become `init(shirtData: Binding<Shirt>,`

Comment: Oh I see! After I applied these changes, I get the error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties on the initialiser for hiding the tab bar. Do I need to do something there too?

Comment: Does that go in the same initialiser as the one used to hide the tab bar or a separate one? And how would the showDetailShirt / showDetailTrouser ones be initialised?

Comment: @mbby Please see my updated answer.

Comment: When I make these changes, when I initialise the Marketplace I get the errors: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Trouser>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Trouser?>' AND Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Shirt>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Shirt?>'

Comment: @mbby Please read my answer. Remove the implicit unwrappings.

Comment: I added my issue in detail. I believe removing implicit unwrapping worked and I need to do something similar here? Every time I do this I get more errors

Comment: @mbby You are expanding the question over and over again. If you take the code you had at the beginning and implement my answer the errors will get away. So I consider this question answered. If you have a new question please open a new one.